# python for loop finish

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm self learning python through out online courses but i ran into a problem .

> for loop

how do i tell python to do something after the for loops is finished ?

for example :

```
def mixer(g):
print(g)

def printer(h):
    print("end")

X = input ("words :  ") 
var2 = ""
var1 = X.split()


for y in var1:
    if len(y) > 5:
        y.upper()
        var2 += y.upper() + " "
        mixer(var2)
    elif len(y)  <= 5:
        y.lower()
        var2 += y.lower() + " "
        mixer(var2)
```

that's what i'm trying to do after for loop is done , i want to call a function after the loop , how can u do this ? ## >>> this method didn't work

```
    elif y == False:
        print("false")
        printer(var2)
```

Comment: Just put the code after the for-loop?

Comment: make sure you un-indent the block of code you want executed after the for-loop. Python uses indentation to figure out what blocks of code belong to a loop or not.

Comment: FYI, when the condition in `elif` is the exact opposite of the `if` condition, you should use `else:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put it outside the body of the for loop:

```
for x in y:
    ... indented block does stuff with x on each loop ...
... dedented code (outside loop body) run once after loop is finished ...
```